# Mobile design guidelines and handoffs

Tags: interface-design, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-first

**Backstory:** I have no previous digital design experience but recently started working as a UI/UX designer for a small company. This is my first job.

**Problem:** We are currently working on a react native app and I'm unsure as to how to proceed with the design. I want the design to be consistent across all devices. My points of confusion are as follows:

1. What screen dimensions do I design for? Do I need to redo my designs for different screens (say, for Pixel 2 and Nexus 4)? as they have different dimensions? or is there a way to have a single design dimension that works for (mostly) all devices?
2. The developer I'm working with too doesn't know much about responsive design, so, while handing over the specs to the developer, what units should the layout dimensions be in? When should I use px and when should I use % values? I would want it to adapt to the screen size so that the developer too doesn't have to rewrite codes for different screens.

Comment: Do you know that there is a [UX Stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)?  To be honest, your question would probably be better asked there, since it isn't really about graphic design as such.

Comment: Answer to your first question: [Should the browser interface size be taken in to account when designing web apps?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/96258/23061). Answer to your second question: [Responsive web design is based on screen resolution or screen size?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/57442/23061).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive web design is based on screen resolution or screen size?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57442/responsive-web-design-is-based-on-screen-resolution-or-screen-size)

Answer (score 0):

I can say regarding android applications. The android applications to adapt to different screen sizes using multiple sizes of the same image. That is, you will need to prepare the image with different sizes. For example, 6 image sizes are used for icons. `512 * 512px`, `192 * 192px`, `144 * 144px`, `96 * 96px`, `72 * 72px`, `48 * 48px`.

I advise you to see [this website](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html). There is auto-generation of icons in the right sizes. Maybe it will direct you in the right direction.